# Unable to install geth 1.5.9 ubuntu

Tags: go-ethereum, installation

I want to install geth 1.5.9 but I find only geth 1.6.0!
How can I install geth with this specific version?

Comment: Which platform are you on? How are you performing the installation? 1.5.9 can be found here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.5.9

Comment: I am using ubuntu 14.04, 64bit! I typed "sudo apt-get install ethereum"!

Comment: I completely missed that the headline actually said "Ubuntu" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sudo apt-get install ethereum` will pull the latest release from the official repository, which at the time of writing is version 1.6.0.

If you want to get your hands on an older version, you have two options:

- download the pre-built binaries/packages from the [Downloads](https://geth.ethereum.org/downloads/) page, or
- download the source from the relevant version's entry in the [Releases](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases) page (under the Downloads section), and build yourself.

**Note:**

In theory, you should also be able to use `apt` to get an older version by specifying the version in the command. For example:

```
sudo apt-get install ethereum=1.5.9
```

However, I can't actually see any older version in the [repository](https://launchpad.net/~ethereum/+archive/ubuntu/ethereum) itself, and the version names are probably too complex to guess given they contain the build number (e.g. `1.6.0+build9491+zesty`).

Comment: If I download from the download page! how can I find the ~\.ethereum to delete the history and create my private network?

Comment: I have tried "sudo apt-get install ethereum="1.5.9+build8841+trusty" but it doesn't works :/

Comment: I'd just download the newer version of Geth from the Downloads page and copy it over the the top of the old one (`/usr/bin/geth`).

Comment: Yes it is removed because only 1.6.0 is displayed `apt-cache showpkg ethereum
                                                          Package: ethereum
                                                         Versions: 
                                                       1.6.0+build9491+trusty (/var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_ethereum_ethereum_ubuntu_dists_trusty_main_binary-amd64_Packages)`

Comment: Okay, so it's definitely not in the repository. You'll have to use one of the other methods.

Comment: (I have an RPi 3B). But when I do `sudo apt-cache show ethereum` I get no packages. Shouldn't apt-cache show at least one ethereum package? Or `does apt-cache` show only show packages installed on my system?